# How to use `allow_redirects` in Python 2.7 in order to solve "302 Found" status

Tags: python, urllib

**Problem Description**

I am using the following the following python code in order to retrieve data from a give website through an API. The problem is that I am not receiving anything. When I `print(str(response.status)+"  "+response.reason)`, I get the following: `302 FOUND` and nothing is being printed. From what I saw `The HTTP response status code 302 Found is a common way of performing URL redirection`.

**Question**

I saw that there is a way to set `allow_redirects` to `False` in order to solve that problem. I am forced to use **python 2.7**. I can't use **python 3.0**. Is there a way to add `allow_redirects` to the request in python 2.7? I also can't use the `requests` library. I can use `import requests`.

---

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sys
import json
import httplib

# Retrieve list of errors from Error Viewer
def retrieve_errors_from_error_viewer(errors):
    headers = {"Content-Type": "application/json","Accept": "text/html"}
    data = {"dba": "XXX", "phase": "PROD"}
    conn = httplib.HTTPConnection('errorviewer.toys.net')
    conn.request('POST', '/api/errors', json.dumps(data), headers)
    response = conn.getresponse()
    print(str(response.status)+"  "+response.reason)
    print(response.read())


if __name__ == "__main__":
    # Retrieve Errors From ErrorViewer
    errors = []
    retrieve_errors_from_error_viewer(errors)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use `httplib2` instead of `httplib`, you have the `follow_all_redirects` option that should solve your problem.

Comment: thank you Tim so much! it worked